# Python string (argument) -> Regex

Tags: python, regex, arguments

I'm trying to take a regular expression as an argument to my python program (which is a string naturally) and simply match it against another string.

Let's say I run it as

`python program.py 'Hi.there'`

I'd like to be able to then take that input (call it input) and say whether or not it matches 'HiTthere' (it should).

How should I do this? I'm inexperienced at regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, you're looking for something like:

```
import sys, re

regex = sys.argv[1]

someOtherString = 'hi there'

found = re.search(regex, someOtherString)
print('ok' if found else 'nope')
```

Run this program with an expression as a first argument:

```
> python test.py hi.th
ok
> python test.py blah
nope
```

Unlike, say, javascript, python regexes are simple strings, so you can directly use `sys.argv[1]` as an argument to `re.search`.

Comment: Okay, cool. This helps (I didn't know that regexes are just strings). Just a quick note, I was looking for the number of times that was found (so instead of search, I'm now using findall)

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 syntax (Python 2, use `print xxx` instead of `print(xxx)`):

```
import re

if re.match(r'^Hi.there$', 'HiTthere'): # returns a "match" object or None
    print("matches")
else:
    print("no match")
```

Note that I'm using the anchors `^` and `$` to guarantee that the match spans the entire input. `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end of the string.

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for much more detail.

Comment: Although, you really only need the `$` anchor since `re.match` starts at the start of the string by default.

Comment: Yep. I find using `^`/`$` as a pair to be more explicit, but you can skip `^`.

Comment: This is helpful, but the thing is that I have the 'Hi.there' as a string object first (as I pass it as an argument to the program, not as a string literal). Can I do the same thing?

Comment: @RiverTam -- Sure.  Just substitute `'HiTthere'` with `sys.argv[1]` (with proper import of course).

Comment: If you are passing the regex as a command-line argument, use `sys.argv[1]` as the first argument (the pattern). If you want to match the entire string using the regex, add a `$`: `sys.argv[1] + '$'`.

Comment: So this just isn't working. My input (which I have as literally 'i') is stored as "phrase_to_look_for", and the string I want to search for is stored in "contents" (and I know it contains the letter i at least once). I'm searching through it as "response = re.match(phrase_to_look_for, contents)", which apparently never passes the "if" test (if response : print 'hi' # hi never gets printed)

Comment: Are you looking for a pattern *in* another string? My answer was for *matching* an entire string with a pattern. To search, use `re.search` and leave off the anchors (`^`/`$`).